# How to solve ODE containing both f(x) and x using dsolve()

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve this ODE using sympy. However `dsolve()`
complaines about my ODE containing several functions. The ODE
have r and u(r) which is suspect is the problem. I have tried solving the ODE using Matlab and this worked without any problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *

init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')

r = Symbol('r')
u = Function('u')(r)

eps_r = u.diff(r)
eps_t = u/r

Eps = Matrix([[eps_r, 0 ,0],
          [0, eps_t, 0],
          [0,0,eps_t]
         ])

L, G = symbols('L G')

x,y = Matrix([1,0,0]),Matrix([0,1,0])

Sig = L*Eps.trace()*eye(3) + 2*G*Eps

sig_r = (x.T*Sig*x)[0]
sig_t = (y.T*Sig*y)[0]

eq1 = diff(sig_r,r) + (sig_r-sig_t)*2/r
eq1 = factor(eq1)
eq1 = eq1/(2*G+L)

dsolve(eq1,r)
```

The matlab code is:

```
syms u(r)

eps_r = diff(u,r);
eps_t = u/r;

Eps = [eps_r 0 0;
       0 eps_t 0;
       0 0 eps_t];

syms L G

Sig = L*trace(Eps)*eye(3) + 2*G*Eps;

x = [1;0;0];
y = [0;1;0];

sig_r = x'*Sig*x
sig_t = y'*Sig*y

eq1 = diff(sig_r,r) + 2/r*(sig_r-sig_t);
eq1 = simplify(eq1)/(2*G + L)

u = dsolve(eq1==0, r)
```

The error, when running `dsolve(eq1,r)` is:

> ValueError: dsolve() and classify_ode() only work with functions of one variable, not r
>
> The expected result, generated with matlab, is:
>
> u(r) = C2/r^2 - (C1*r)/3

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to dsolve should be the function (including argument) that you want to solve for e.g. `f(x)`. In your case that is `u(r)` although confusingly you've called that `u` so:

```
In [6]: dsolve(eq1, u)                                                                                                                         
Out[6]: 
       C₁       
u(r) = ── + C₂⋅r
        2       
       r
```

Comment: This is what I though actually but when I run it: dsolve(eq1,u)


I get the following error message:


NotImplementedError: solve: Cannot solve (r**2*Derivative(u(r), (r, 2)) + 2*r*Derivative(u(r), r) - 2*u(r))/r**2